# How Can I Download a Single Packet from Wireshark

Tags: python, wireshark, packet-sniffers, packets, wireshark-dissector

I have this problem where I need to compare two packets and see if they are different. I am trying to write a python script to do this.
However, to do this I think I need to download individual packets before I can compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
File > Export Specified Packets..
```